# Install python package on a specific folder instead of user level

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip

So I am currently working on a DevOps task for a Python repository.
I am tasked with making the repository work properly with our Docker environment.

My current issue is that when running `pip3 install`, it installs everything in various folders that have nothing to do with the current repository path.
This is not ideal when working with `docker-compose` for a local development environment.

What we want to achieve is to install `pip` dependencies once on the host machine and then mount them as a dynamic volume inside the docker container. The reason is simple, we want to be able to destroy the container as many times as we want without having to download everything again. Because this is an AI repository, you can imagine that the `pip` dependencies are heavy and take a lot of time to download. We currently have about 5 to 10GB of dependencies to download depending on the branch and current code progress.

Ideally, I'd like `pip` to behave like Node.JS tools such as `yarn` or `npm` where it builds a local folder (like `node_modules`) that I can easily mount inside the container.

I have looked through the `pip` documentation but I simply can't find a way to do this at all.

**Is there a way to constrain `pip` and `python` to install dependencies inside a specific folder and to only use those dependencies?**

Comment: A normal Docker setup has self-contained immutable images.  There are tricks you can do to avoid re-installing dependencies when only the application code changes, but the setup you describe of having significant required parts of the application stored in volumes rather than images isn't normally a best-practice Docker setup.  If this is for a development setup, would a plain-Python virtual environment without Docker work better?

Comment: @DavidMaze You are referring to production-aimed best practices. When using Docker for local development it is the opposite. You absolutely do not want static images because you (obviously) need to edit the code base and keep it evolving constantly. It's unrealistic to have to rebuild the image after every minor change made to the code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Docker Approach

You can just split up your dependencies into a separate docker image which serves as the basis for your current image. This way you only need to build base-image once and then only when the dependencies change.

*Base Image Example*

```
FROM python:3.10-bullseye

# Copy requirements into container and install
COPY ./requirements.txt .
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Build with `docker build -t myImage .`

*Actual Image*

```
FROM myImage

# setup for everything else
```

### Python Approach

In general pip provides the `--target` option to install the packages into a specific directory instead of the `site-packages` folder [see documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-t).

However, the use of a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) is recommended to separate the dependencies from the host into an environment, which can then be mounted into a docker-container.

```
# create venv once
python -m venv /path/myVenv
# enter venv
source /path/myVenv/bin/activate
# install dependencies
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then you can just mount `/path/myVenv` into the container and `source` again to access it.

Comment: Activating a virtual environment in something like a Dockerfile seems likely to fail. I recommend to use commands like `path/to/venv/bin/pip install ...` instead.

Comment: (A Python virtual environment is extremely specific to its filesystem path and the specific Python it was built for; you probably can't mount a prebuilt virtual environment into a container.  Just run it without involving Docker.)

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it is the most detailed one but @MosGeo also had a correct one.
I'd like to not, however, that dynamic volumes are indeed mandatory in this situation so using a multi-stage build is not a satisfying solution.
It did work by creating a `venv` and mounting it as a volume.
Regarding the remark from @DavidMaze, you can mount an empty folder and build the `venv` from within the container which will persist the files and still have the correct build environment.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using virtual environments:

1. Setup a virtual environment in your persistent mounted shared folder.
2. Install all dependencies in your virtual environment.
3. Mount the drive to your container.
4. Activate the virtual environment
5. Now, when you use python commands, they will be from the virutal environment.

ps. simplist way to setup virtual environment is using (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) but there are other solutions to do that too.

Comment: Activating a virtual environment in something like a Dockerfile seems likely to fail. I recommend to use commands like `path/to/venv/bin/pip install ...` instead.